# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Server Error, status=500

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've got Spring Boot app, which works on localhost. But after deploy .war file on my server on some pages i recieve:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jan 26 15:49:46 CET 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [/user/instruction/disable-script], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

On localhost this page is working. Problem is only on server.

[image]

disable-script.html:

```
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorate="~{fragments/user/layout}">
<head>
    <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="content" th:remove="tag">
.....
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller fragment:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user/instruction/disable-script", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String instructionDisableScript(WebRequest request, Model model) {
        return "/user/instruction/disable-script";
    }
```

Some pages on server are working. I don't have any idea why some of them are throwing this error 500...

Comment: Try removing the first `/` from the return. So you would have `return "user/instruction/disable-script"` instead.

Comment: 500 is internal server error. Have you read the server's log file? Perhaps it could give you additional information. Please add the log in your question if you find it.

Comment: What is Spring Boot version?

Comment: @DoNhuVt - Spring Boot 2.2.2 RELEASE.

Comment: Alain Cruz - it was too simply... You are right. I added on begining few "/" and that was the problem. Thank you very much for help. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe because after deployment, the lookup of the templates changes, try running your server with the following configuration: `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/`

Comment: There is that line in application.properties. @Alan Cruz was right, there were one unnecessary "/" in controller, when i was trying to return my HTML.